# Calling javascript function from native android activity code

Tags: android, html

I have following Test Android App.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/test.html");        
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sudoku, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Need to call javascript function testFun() here (see test.html)
  }
}
```

Code for test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function testFun()
     {
       alert('Hi');
    }
  </script
  <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="testFun()">Test</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I read about calling android functions in javascript http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

But could not get how to call javascript functions from android (menu item click).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried this.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:testFun()");
```